# How do you create an android emulator with multiple back cameras

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to work on stereo video capture using two back cameras of an android device. Since I don't have a device with android pie and two back cameras on hand, I've been trying to create an emulator with the above specifications. But I'm unable to find any resources on how I can create a hardware profile with two back cameras. Is it possible to do this in android studio 3.3

Comment: what have you done so far??

Comment: what kind of devices are you talking about?

Comment: I don't have a very firm grasp on android emulator so I wen through the available options in android studio and didn't find anything.

Comment: Any device with multiple back cameras so that I can try to emulate a capture of a stereo image

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the new multi-camera API introduced for Android P.

The API search for the physical camera sensors/components, so i do not know if you can emulate all of its features without a physical device. But the best you can do is to emulate a **Google Pixel 3** or a **Huawei Mate 20 Pro** (or Mate 20 series) phone, with a camera enabled.

**Summary:** I suggest you to emulate a Pixel 3 from Android Studio, and use the API, I think you can implement some easy functions such as zooming or differentiate between the physical and logical cameras. But if try to implement serious features, then you need to get a physical phone with multi-camera support from Android side.